# Are these block foundation cracks problematic?

Tags: foundation, crack, basement-refinishing, concrete-block, cinderblock

What steps should I take to address these cracks and how problematic are they? I am hoping to insulate and finish this exterior wall.

[image: foundation cracks]

Comment: Only you can determine how problematic they are, and what you should do is subjective. Does water come in? Do insects come in? Do you see evidence of settling in the finished area above? Please revise to ask a more specific question. Note that there are many existing foundation block crack questions on this site to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

If you have granular soil under your foundation, then apply a *concrete* sealant with a class 25 rating under ASTM C920. If you have a cohesive soil like clay under your foundation, then apply a *concrete* sealant with the highest class rating under ASTM C920 that you can find (class 25 is still pretty good, but I found a class 35 sealant on my first try). Then you can bury that sucker.

The step pattern cracking without inward or outward movement is associated with foundation settlement. Structurally it's probably no big deal. Differential settlement may cause nuisance issues like cracked wall finishes and doors that rub against their casings, but nothing catastrophic. Looking for a kink at your crack location, my eye doesn't register anything, where I expect to see a significant kink before I expect to see those nuisance issues arising. You would know better than I by any problematic doors, walls, out of level floors, etc. (old windows used to stick, but modern ones probably are fine with quite a bit of movement).

For granular soils like sand and gravel, the settlement under the house's weight takes about 6 months. Any differential settlement problems in this case can be mitigated a year or so after construction with the expectation of no further work. For cohesive soils like clays, however, settlement can take decades, making mitigation an endless nuisance.

On sealing the existing cracks against insect intrusion and air, you want a stretchy sealant with good adhesion. ASTM C920 tests sealants for stretchiness and adhesion, so that's a good spec to look at for comparing sealants.

Quickly searching, I found that GE makes a concrete silicone product that's class 25 under ASTM C920. The "class 25" indicates that the product's adhesion survived stretching by 25% of a test joint's width (but it presumably doesn't survive under the next tier of performance, 35%). I found a YouTube video of the cyclic test (ASTM C719) that gets used if you're interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3k4chr8tSDM. The "concrete" qualifier for such a product is very important, as it indicates that the adhesion was tested with a concrete substrate.

I also found that Sika's Sikaflex product has a class 35 rating under ASTM C920, so that would be a slightly better performing alternative to the GE product. If you're wandering around a hardware store looking for *anything* that will work, though, I would read some fine print looking for an adequate ASTM C920 class (concrete substrate. Concrete, concrete, concrete). Granular soil? Class 25 is probably fine. Cohesive soil (like clay)? Then I would get the highest class I could find, because your cracks may grow in the future.